Uneven stepper motor acceleration / code execution
I have created a library to control a stepper motor. I have a controller that accepts a pull signal, and then executes a step, so my code needs to generate a state change in order to make the controller execute a single step.
I have a part of the code responsible for acceleration. It runs in main loop as often as possible. The acceleration is given in steps/s/s and speed in steps/s. Here is the method in question:
void StepperMotor::accelerate() {
  speed = start_accelerating_speed + (micros() - startAccelTime) / 1000000.0 * acceleration;
  step_time = 1000000 / speed;
}

start_accelerating_speed is set to micros() when the motor starts. Let's say acceleration = 200.
The step_time is used by the code in the main loop to check if it is time to make a step.
The code seems to work fine, however, when executed, the motor starts accelerating as expected, then increases speed rapidly by let's say 10% of the target speed and keeps accelerating smoothly for some time. This pattern repeats. Jumps can be only heard from changing motor speed or buzzer sound (I use a buzzer instead of a motor for easy debugging). Printing speeds on the serial port kills the performance completely making the code wait for the serial port.
I have used this code to measure loop time without adding a significant Serial.println() overhead.
// Runs in main loop, loops and step_time defined earlier.
loops++;
if (loops >= 10000) {
  Serial.println(micros()-loop_time);
  loop_time = micros();
  loops = 0;
}

Conclusion: the loop takes about 56 microseconds to execute, less than 70 when motor is running and accelerating. Running the stepper motor in this setup with 1000 steps per second requires a min. loop time of 1000 microseconds (or 1 millisecond). The code should run smoothly.
I ran the code in pure C++ and plotted the results in Matlab. The result is linear acceleration.
I have tried slowing down the main loop to 50 ms per loop, and slowing down the motor and acceleration accordingly so I could also print the speeds on serial port; then everything works fine.
Any form of delay() is never used in the code.
Tested with ATmega 328 and ATmega 2560 with same results.
It's been about a month and I can't find a similar issue on the internet.
Does anyone know what might be happening here?
P.S.
I know that linear acceleration is sub-optimal, but I'd like to resolve the current issue first.
I'm including the full source code for this class. I have stripped down the code to the bare minimum. The issue still persists. The tone of the buzzer seems to be affected by enabling the second motor, printing on serial port etc. regardless of the fact that execution of the loop never exceeds 1 ms.
main.cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <StepperMotor.h>

StepperMotor motor_1(3, 2, 4);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  motor_1.start();
}

void loop(void) {   
  motor_1.update();
}

StepperMotor.cpp

// Constructor
StepperMotor::StepperMotor(uint8_t step_pin_, uint8_t enable_pin_, uint8_t direction_pin_):
step_pin(step_pin_), enable_pin(enable_pin_), direction_pin(direction_pin_) {
  // Initiating pinouts
  pinMode(step_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(direction_pin, OUTPUT);

  // Setting pin states
  digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(enable_pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(direction_pin, LOW);
}

// Called while accelerating. Recalculate speed and check if target speed has been reached.
void StepperMotor::accelerate() {
  // Using start time - calculate current speed and step time.
  speed = start_accelerating_speed + (micros() - startAccelTime) / 1000000.0 * acceleration;
  step_time = 1000000 / speed;

  // Stop accelerating if target speed is reached
  if (speed >= target_speed) {
    accelerating = false;
  }
  // Serial.println(speed);
}

// Realising basic steps needed to start motor and prepare variables.
void StepperMotor::startMotion() {
  Serial.println("Start"); // Debug

  // Prepare variables for step control
  prev_step_time = time;
  speed = 0;
  step_time = 0;

  // Prepare acceleration
  startAccelTime = time;
  start_accelerating_speed = 0;
  accelerating = true; // Enable acceleration
}

// Overloaded methods for starting a motor.
// Start in the same direstion and speed as before.
void StepperMotor::start() {
  startMotion();
}

void StepperMotor::update() { // Main control method. Executed in loop by Stepper.cpp
  time = micros();

  if (time-prev_step_time >= step_time) { // Is it time to step?
    step_pin_state = !step_pin_state;    // Alter pin variable
    digitalWrite(step_pin, step_pin_state);    // Write pin state to pinout

    prev_step_time = time;
  }

  if (accelerating) { // If target speed not reached: accelerate
    accelerate();
  }
}

StepperMotor.h
// StepperMotor.h

#ifndef STEPPERMOTOR_H
#define STEPPERMOTOR_H

#include <Arduino.h>

class StepperMotor {
public:
  // Constructor
  StepperMotor(uint8_t step_pin_, uint8_t enable_pin_, uint8_t direction_pin_);

  // Methods
  void start();

  // Main loop method called by StepperController
  void update();

private:
  // Pins
  uint8_t step_pin;      // Change of state = 1 step.
  uint8_t enable_pin;    // 0 = Disabled  1 = Enabled
  uint8_t direction_pin; // 0 = CW        1 = CCW
    
  double target_speed = 1000; // In steps per second

  // Timers
  unsigned long time;
  unsigned long startAccelTime;
  unsigned long startAccelTimeMillis;
  unsigned long step_time; // Indicates time between steps in microseconds
  unsigned long prev_step_time;
  unsigned long prev_accel_time;       // Usually the same as prev_stepTime //change comment

  double speed;        // Indicates the motor's speed in steps per second
  bool step_pin_state; // Indicates current state of step pin. FALSE = LOW; TRUE = HIGH

  bool direction;      // Indicates the motor's rotation direction
  bool moving;         // Indicates if stepper is moving or not. Do not confuse with enable - enable can be used to hold motor in place.

  void startMotion();
  void accelerate();

  bool accelerating = false;
  double acceleration = 200; // In steps per second^2
  double start_accelerating_speed;
};

#endif // STEPPERMOTOR_H



Please include a complete compilable code in your question. The problem might be in the rest of the code and not in the little snippet, that you showed.

Thank you for your answer. The snippet is a part of quite large library. Even though I think that most if not all of the class' code does not affect the issue - I have edited the original post with full class source code. I hope it can be quite easily ran without the rest of library.
Please also note that I develop the code via platformio on VSCode, hence the  library is included.

There is quite a lot going on in this library. Some suggestions: 1. Remove everything but the core algorithm you want to test, in order to get a minimal testable example. If it still shows the problem, update the question and replace your library with that example. 2. Instrument loop() to measure the maximum (not average) loop execution time. 3. Call micros() only once in update(), and don't call it again in accelerate(): for consistency, you want all computations to be based on the same notion of “current update time”.

Thanks for suggestions @EdgarBonet. I will set micros only once in a loop from now as a good practice. I have measured maximum loop time. It's at most ~340 µs (when motor accelerates). A bit more than I would like but probably occurs only several times in the time period as average was much lower. Nevertheless it's lower than max of 1000 µs required to test speed of 1000 steps/s. I will replace the code with stripped down version if/when i create it. For now the problem persists and I still have some things to try first.

I tested this sketch by looking at the step pin on an oscilloscope. What
I see is a square signal with a period that decreases smoothly at first,
then in a manner that gets more and more jerky, with visible jumps.
It turns out this is due to the time taken by the loop() iterations.
On my tests, it takes about 85 µs. Doesn't look like much, but it
has a significant impact on the timings, because the signal period has
to be a multiple of the loop() execution period. When the signal
period is large, this constraint does not cause any visible effect. When
the signal period is short, however, the fact that it decreases by
integer multiples of the loop() period makes visible jumps. The last
jump is a variation by about 8.5% (85 µs / 1 ms).
The solution is to change the way the prev_step_time variable is
updated. In the current version of the code, it is updated as
prev_step_time = time;

This means that prev_step_time stores the time when the previous step
was performed. You may instead update it like this:
prev_step_time += step_time;  // increment by step period

In this case, that variable holds the time at which the previous step
was scheduled. This implies that timing errors are not cumulative: if
one signal period is a bit too long because of the above mentioned
rounding, then this will be compensated by the next period being
shorter. In the end, you do get some jitter, but no systematic frequency
errors.

Edit: Your program is calling accelerate() to re-compute the step
period at every loop() iteration. Most of these computations are just
thrown away. All this involves quite a bit of floating point
computations, which makes the main loop slow. You would get a smoother
movement if you recompute the step period only after having performed a
step. The algorithm is as follows:
if (it's time to do a step):
    do the step
    compute next step period

As a first approximation, the next step period is equal to the previous
one, and the average speed within that period is equal to the expected
speed at the middle of that time interval. This speed can then be used
to compute a better approximation of the next step period, which gives
the following formula for updating the step period:
step_period ← 1 / speed(current_step_time + step_period / 2)

I tried this strategy and, according to my scope, the frequency sweep is
indeed smoother. Here is my test code. Note that I did change some
notations:
// Return the speed (in steps/s) at time t (in us).
// Implementation skipped.
double speed(unsigned long t);

void update()
{
    // Do nothing until it's time to perform a step.
    if (micros() - prev_step_time < step_period)
        return;

    // Do the step.
    step_pin_state = !step_pin_state;
    digitalWrite(step_pin, step_pin_state);

    // Update timing variables.
    prev_step_time += step_period;
    step_period = 1e6 / speed(prev_step_time + step_period/2);
}

Note that now, most iterations of loop() will do nothing other than
evaluate
if (micros() - prev_step_time < step_period) return;

which makes the loop very fast and improves the smoothness of the
acceleration.
There is one caveat with this approach though: the start of the movement
is very sensitive to the initial value of step_period. I found no
better idea than to initialize it at the exact value for the first step:
step_period = 1e6 * sqrt(2/acceleration);

The square root is expensive to compute, but this is done only once.

Absolutely brilliant :)

Your answer seems to be on point. The oscilloscope must have helped a bit. Honestly, I had thought about the multiples of loop time being the limiting factor, but I didn't think it would make such a difference. Your answer helped me as much as it was possible. However, I can see that the issue persists to some level. I think it is okay for now, but I assume that I'd need to get something with a faster clock to achieve smoother operation. All things considered, I've checked the AccelStepper library, and it does not support speeds larger than 1000 - so it seems like the clock is the limit.

@WojciechKosela: see amended answer.

@EdgarBonet thank you, that's very interesting. You've presented me with a new approach to the issue. I will continue my journey with this topic and post any new ideas, if I find any in the future. I hope it will help the others.

For anyone who might be looking up this topic in the future, I want to post some of my findings, directions and keywords regarding this question.
I have been experiencing large jumps in speed when accelerating. Now I know why.
Time between steps changes slowly with larger speeds. As time measurements were limited by loop time - only possible values of time were: n * loop time. With this in mind - jumps i experienced were caused by executing step each n-1 loops (assuming that previously it was executed each n loops). As my loop took about 80us it was very noticeable and fooled me into thinking that limited loop frequency can't be the sole reason for this. It can.
For anyone having the same problem as me. I have a STRONG ADVICE. Use Arduino timer/counter. That's what I did. It is designed for this purpose and it's the proper way. Don't know how to use timers? Learn it. Even if you think that it is overkill for what you are trying to do. Firstly: you can't unlearn it, so you won't be leaving empty handed no matter what. Secondly: if you try implementing anything more into this code, i.e. serial communication - It will interrupt the timings and you will never have peace with this timings. Timers (interrupts) eliminate all those issues.
And at last some important notes about timer interrupts. Use carefully. Some timers are used by Arduino for things like millis() / micros(). All the timers are used for PWM outputs. Choose wisely and be aware what are you disabling by using a given timer.
Also read some "don't"s of what can be done inside timer interrupts. Basically avoid anything that itself uses interrupts, so digitalWrite(), Serial.print(), delay(). For pin outputs you have to use port manipulation.
It is a lot of to worry about, but if you are reading this topic - you might be wanting to generate some precise signal with Arduino. If that's the case - you better try using timers/counters, it would probably take you less time than troubleshooting (and realizing you have to use interrupts anyway) regular timers.

That's good advice: timers are a bit complex but can definitively give you spot-on timings. Some remarks: 1. The best timings are achieved with PWM mode, by updating the compare register in the timer interrupt ISR. 2. digitalWrite() does not rely on interrupts. The reason you may prefer direct port manipulation is because it is way faster.

@EdgarBonet Instead of direct port access I prefer the library "digitalWriteFast" by Watterot/Armin Joachimsmeyer, that compiles to single instructions, of course only with compile-time constant parameters. (Disclaimer: I know how to use SFRs. But this way it is much more intuitive and beginner-friendly.)

@EdgarBonet it may be true that digitalWrite() does not rely on interrupts. Also, as far as i know it takes about 4us per write, where port manipulation takes one or a few clock cycles (~0.1 us). Nevertheless I have experienced catastrophic events when updating pins with digitalWrite() during ISR. Whatever was happening, it resulted with memory corruption and subsequent controller crash, a few lines of code later. Diverging from digitalWrite() to port manipulation fixed the issue, although it might have been for another reason than I remember.
